# angularjs .reject not returning to then function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-promise

I am unable to find the bug in my code, but $q.defer().reject() does not seem to work as it should be. defer.resolve works fine, even goes to the finally segment, but defer.reject (though doesn't throw any error but) doesn't return to the then function nor to the finally function
I am using angularjs version 1.5.8

```
// calling service 
DashboardFactory.getDashboard($scope.dashboardData.dsDetails.dashName).then(
                    function (response) {
                        debugger;
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    function () {
                        console.log('reject');
                    }
                ).finally(function() {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('finally');
             });

// service 
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function() {
                    $http(httpParams)
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            defer.resolve(data);
                        })
                        .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log('error');
                            defer.reject('error');
                        })
                }, 0);
                return defer.promise;
```

Comment: have you checked with API failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q` is a service that allows you to run functions asynchronously and you can use promises.

But `$http` service methods `get post put ...`  already return a promise so you don't need it, but if you really insist to use it you can use it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);
      app.service('YourService', function($http, $q) {
        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";
        this.getUserWithQ = function(id) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $http.get(url+id).then(
            function(data) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            function(error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
            }
          );
          return deferred.promise;
        };
        this.getUserWithoutQ = function(id) {
          return $http.get(url+id);
        }
      })
      app.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, YourService) {
        YourService.getUserWithQ(1).then(
          function(res) {
            $scope.userWithQ = res.data;
          },
          function(error) {
            //unused
          }
        );
        YourService.getUserWithQ(11).then(
          function(res) {
            //unused
          },
          function(error) {
            $scope.userWithQerror = error;
          }
        );
        //Just for the record
        YourService.getUserWithoutQ(1).then(
          function(res) {
            $scope.userWithoutQ = res.data;
          },
          function(error) {
            //unused
          }
        );
        YourService.getUserWithoutQ(11).then(
          function(res) {
            //unused
          },
          function(error) {
            $scope.userWithoutQerror = error;
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="yourApp">
    <div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
      <div> 
        <div>
          With $q success:
          {{userWithQ}}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
          With $q error:
          {{userWithQerror}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div> 
        <div>
          Without $q success:
          {{userWithoutQ}}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
          With $q error :
          {{userWithQerror}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've used this api as example `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/` that has 10 users and the 11 will produce an error.

As you can see, you can get the same result with both `$q.defer()` and `$http` return value.

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/g0TS2lx9a4QVfMsmc5w5?p=preview)